# SQL Server : convert Into prepared statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, prepared-statement

The folllowing code is vulnerable to SQL injection and I am trying to correct the code of previous developer; he used `DataTable` to further use query - how do I use prepare statement along with data table?

```
string data = "";
int i = 1;

cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from maincategory where isactive=1 and id in (select catid from productmaster where isactive=1)", con);

con.Open();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
con.Close();

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
     data += "<ul>";

     foreach (DataRow DR in dt.Rows)
     {
         data += "<li><a href='product.aspx?cid="+DR["id"]+"'>" + DR["catname"] + "</a></li>";
     }

     data += " </ul>";
}

lblpartners.Text = data;
```

The code that I tried:

```
public void show()
{    
     string data = "";
     int i = 1;

     cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from maincategory where isactive=@val1 and id in (select catid from productmaster where isactive=@val2)", con);

     con.Open();
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", 1);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", 1);

     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     dt.Load(cmd.Prepare());
     con.Close();

     if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
     {
        data += "<ul>";

        foreach (DataRow DR in dt.Rows)
        {
            data += "<li><a href='product.aspx?cid="+DR["id"]+"'>" + DR["catname"] + "</a></li>";
        }

        data += " </ul>";
    }

    lblpartners.Text = data;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error /issue in code which you try ?

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.DataTable.Load(System.Data.IDataReader)' has some invalid arguments httpdocs

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Data.IDataReader'

Comment: FWIW, I dont see an injection vulnerability in the first code

Comment: data += "<li><a href='product.aspx?cid="+DR["id"]+"'>" + DR["catname"] + "</a></li>";

this line is injectable

http://example.com/product.aspx?cid=@@version
http://www.example.com/product.aspx?cid=db_name()

Comment: Oh I see, you're worried about an XSS injection, not a SQL injection. If you use XML manipulation methods instead of using string concatenation, I'm pretty sure they will protect you against XSS injections (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/xdocument-class-overview)

Comment: i dont think so the query is vulnerable since you have hard coded active value not using user supplied

Answer (score 0):

`SqlCommand.Prepare` doesn't return an IDataReader, [it's a void method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare?view=netframework-4.7.2). `DataReader.Load()` requires an `IDataReader` object.

Perhaps you meant `dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())`?